# Cp plot in decision tree only showing upward trend

Tags: machine-learning, r, regression, statistics, decision-trees

In Cp plot for decision tree, we expect the error to drop down with size of the tree (or form an elbow). This helps to select right Cp value. But in my graph, the relative error is continuously increasing (please refer to the attached picture).

Am I doing something wrong and how to decide the right Cp here?

[image: cp plot for decision tree]

Comment: It's strange indeed that you don't have any decrease in error at least at the beginning. I guess it looks as if the features don't help predicting the response variable at all (but I could be wrong). Maybe check that the data you give to the algorithm looks correct?

Comment: Data is correct, but the reasons I could see is due to imbalance data this pattern might be. When I applied SMOTE it came back to regular..

Comment: Any chance you could provide the data and code? I'm very interested in any example where oversampling helps substantially.

Comment: Hi @Ben, sorry the data is confidential so could not share but here SMOTE helped..

Comment: One more thing to add here, we could see such pattern if we have one variable highly correlated to target variable. So essentially it indicates that having just one variable will minimize the error and adding further variables will include unnecessary error and cost complexity in the model.